# iOS 5 GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glRenderbufferStorage

Tags: ios5, opengl-es-2.0

I just updated to iOS 5 and get the GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glRenderbufferStorage.

code:

```
RenderingEngine::RenderingEngine(...)
{
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_hColorRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_hColorRenderBuffer);
    ...
}

void RenderingEngine::Initialize(...)
{
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB565, s_ScreenWidth, s_ScreenHeight);
    ...
}
```

Instrument says:
*Responsible Command:*
**GL_INVALID_OPERATION** <- **glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB565, 640, 960)**

*Recommendation:*
**The specified operation is invalid for the current OpenGL state. Due to this error, the function call has no effect.**

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRenderbufferStorage.xml says:
**GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the reserved renderbuffer object name 0 is bound.**

I already confirmed that the **m_hColorRenderBuffer** is **1**. Also tried calling **glBindRenderBuffer** again in **Initialize()**. The result is the same.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.